# Run a aws command using Jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins

I set up a Jenkins job to run an aws command. When I execute the build, it fails and the error message is:

```
+ /usr/local/aws/bin/aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environments
/tmp/hudson3332739386589747399.sh: 2: /tmp/hudson3332739386589747399.sh: /usr/local/aws/bin/aws: not found 
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Make sure to have IAM permissions to your AWS account on jenkins

Comment: Have you specified Access Key ID/Secret Access Key/Region ?

Comment: For the Access Keys and Region,yeah I specified them

Comment: @ahmed, no problem! Glad to help. I have posted this as the answer. Please mark it as your solution to properly close out this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to have appropriate permissions for Jenkins to access your AWS Account in your IAM role or permission set that it assumes.